# JavaScript display remote content

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building an affiliate system and in interested in knowing which would be the most reliable way to display remote banners.  I mean for the affiliates to grab a piece of code and use it to display banners,  it whatever on their sites.

Doesnt have to be JavaScript and I'm using php

Comment: Hey, to display an image (banner), you can give an URL to a PHP script that generate images using an affiliate id. I don't understand the "for the affiliates to grab a price if code and use it to display banners".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two simplest ways I can think of are:

1. To have the server side generate an image, like Mathias said, then the affiliate would need to add something like `<img src="http://your.site.name/script.php">`.
2. Have the affiliate use an iframe, then you can return whatever HTML you need, and they need to add something like `<iframe src="http://your.site.name/script.php">` to their pages.

Google ads, on the other hand, use javascript to generate that iframe, which gives them greater flexibility, at the cost of a more complex solution on their end.

Comment: can the script produce an embedded swf?

Comment: @whatshakin You can have the affiliates use an `<object>` snippet, much like youtube does it. You can have the php return whatever kind of file you like.

Answer (score 1):

I strongle suggest u to use ajax

Sample javascript ajax codes

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```